# Chebychev points and floating point precision

Tags: floating-point, interpolation, precision, floating-accuracy, numerical-analysis

I've seen in my lecture notes that the Chebychev points, defined (in MatLab notation) as

```
n = 20;
i = (1:n+1)';
% Chebychev
xi = 5*cos((2*i-1)*pi/(2*(n+1)))
```

are not symmetric in [-1,1] in floating point precision. **But,** if one uses the trigonometric identity `cos(x) = sin( pi/2 - x)` applied to the points above, he finds out that the Chebychev points

```
xxi = 5*sin(pi*(n+2-2*i)/(2*(n+1)))
```

are now symmetric in the interval.

Now, the big question: why does this substitution gives the symmetry? I'm pretty sure that this has to do with the `pi`, but it appears in both the formulations, so what is really going on? I'd like to see a formal argument or a mathematical computation of such a situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sine formula uses points distributed symmetrically around zero, and the cosine format does not. The features of the floating-point format, notably the granularity with which it represents numbers, is symmetric around zero, and therefore calculations that are symmetric around zero produce results that are symmetric around zero.

The cosine formula uses `cos` at the points (2*i*−1)/(2*n*+2) π for 1 ≤ i ≤ n+1. For *n*=20, these points are 1/42 π, 3/42 π, 5/42 π,… 41/42 π.

1/42 π is about .075. The greatest power of two not greater than .075 is 2<sup>−4</sup>. When 1/42 π is calculated in the IEEE-754 binary64 format, which has 53 bits in its significand, the floating-point scaling is such that the greatest bit position in the significand represents 2<sup>−4</sup>, and the lowest bit position represents 2<sup>−56</sup>. So the result must be rounded to the nearest multiple of 2<sup>−56</sup>. In contrast, 41/42 π is about 3.067, and the leading bit position of its significand represents 2<sup>2</sup>, while the lowest bit position represents 2<sup>−50</sup>. So the result must be rounded to the nearest multiple of 2<sup>−50</sup>, a scale 64 times greater than that for 1/42 π. So the rounding errors in floating-point calculations are generally different for 1/42 π and 41/42 π, for 3/42 π and 39/42 π, and so on.

The sine formula uses `sin` at the points (*n*+2-2*i*)/(2*n*+2) π for 1 ≤ i ≤ n+1. For *n*=20, these points are 20/42 π, 18/42 π, 16/42 π, … −16/42 π, −18/42 π, −20/42 π. In this, when 20/42 π and −20/42 π are calculated in binary64, they both use the same scaling for the significand. So their rounding errors are identical, except in sign, and, the calculated results are identical except for the sign bit. Similarly, 18/42 π and −18/42 π use the same scaling, and all the terms are paired with a symmetric partner, except for 0/42 π, but that is zero and has a calculation error (zero) that is symmetric with itself.

Further, typical implementations of the `sin` routine are symmetric around zero, so that `sin(-x)` and `-sin(x)` produce identical results. Commonly, they operate by reducing the argument modulo 2π (at least in effect) and evaluating a polynomial that approximates sine, and that polynomial is typically symmetric around zero (has all odd powers of its variable *x*). So evaluating `sin(x)` and `sin(-x)` preserves the symmetry, and so does the final multiplication by 5. (`cos` implementations may have a similar symmetry, but, since the arguments in this case are already asymmetric, `cos` cannot restore symmetry.)

Comment: I recall many `sin` implementations actually doing things in a slightly different order: first they discard the sign, and only then do they reduce the argument modulo 2π. This saves the headache of reducing negative arguments. Getting `sin(x)==sin(-x)` is just a nice side-effect.

Answer (score 1):

Both `sin` and `cos` have a period of 2*pi, and as you know the two functions can be easily transformed into each other. There are more relations, such as sin(-x)=-sin(x), cos(-x)=cos(x), sin(x+2pi)=sin(x), etc.

Your original set of points samples cos(x) on the interval 0,2*pi. That's one full period. That's more than enough for computational purposes; in fact the interval 0,pi/2 is already sufficient. Other values of cos(x) can be found be aforementioned relations.

Now the substitution just transforms x ∈ 0,2*pi to x' ∈ -pi, +pi. That's still one full period, but now symmetrical around 0.

Comment: Yes, but how does this affect floating point precision? I mean, why symmetry  holds *numerically* now?

Comment: @andereBen: I have no idea why you are connecting the two questions. "I mean"  suggests to me that you think both questions are just different ways of expressing the same idea, but they're pretty unrelated. They're symmetric because `-(-pi)=+pi`.

Comment: Yes, but if you look at the 16-th decimal digit obtained with the first formulation ,they are not symmetric *up to machine precision* 
With the second formulation, they are

Comment: The fact that sine and cosine are periodic is irrelevant to the question of symmetry. The period enables the cosine formula to be easily transformed to the sine formula, but we might have some formula f(x) on points x that can be transformed to a formula g(t(x)) on points t(x), and f(x) might be non-periodic but have the property that, for the set of points used, each point x0 in the set has a point x1 such that f(x0) = −f(x1). g is also non-periodic but has the property that g(z) = −g(z), and t is such that t(x0) = −t(x1) for the same pairs…

Comment: … Then the results of computing f(x) will generally not be symmetric but the results of computing g(t(x)) will. The only part of this answer that speaks to this is the final words, “now symmetrical around 0.”